# Is it OK to use Hex's as database IDs?

Tags: mysql, database-design, hex

I've just been handed a database schema that looks a little odd to me. The database sits behind a Soap web service and I've noticed that all the table ID's are strings in hex format

eg: 0x1D283F

I'm going to have to duplicate the data into a MySQL database. I've never used Hex's as IDs, so I've no idea wether it's a good idea / bad idea or doesn't matter either way. I'm guessing Auto Increment wouldn't work here, which makes me think this is going to be a bad idea.

I could convert them to integers, or leave them as they are, but what are the implications.

Comment: I suspect the hex is purely a representation of a number which could be an identity field.

Comment: If you insert the hex without quoting into an integer field (`insert into x values (0x1d283f)`), MySQL converts it for you. When you select MySQL returns `1910847`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, whether a number is 'hexadecimal' or 'decimal' is just a matter of outer representation, it doesn't change the storage format. Using strings of numbers as database indices is obviously inefficient and may prevent certain db features and optimizations, though.

Therefore, convert the hex strings to plain integers and use them as database indices and you'll be fine.

Comment: +1 for integers, but depending on the amount of data it will not make much of a difference especially if you have to maintain a link between your duplicate and the original. Plenty of people use GUIDs for primary keys :-(

Comment: Yes, but you can quite easy convert an integer back to a hex string and use it to access the old database, can't you?

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking, you want your primary keys to be meaningless, and (obviously) unique. Hex is just one way of representing a number - underneath, it's still an integer. So, I'd convert to int before storing in the DB.

Bigger question is - are you sure they're unique? If not, you can't use them as your primary key....

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea.  SELECTs will be faster with integer keys.  There might be advantages to using string keys in some instances, but using numeric values stored as strings as keys is just silly.